# Magento2 and Oauth 2.0

Tags: rest-api

Magento 2.2.4  how can in use Oauth 2.0 for rest api resource access?
Is it posible to use Oauth 2.0 with magento 2.2.4 like Oauth 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Currently Magento 2.2 supports oAuth 1.0a.

There are a few ways to implement this and recommend reading the devdocs page for further information: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html